# How to find out particular word "UNMAPPED" from several "UNMAPPED"

Tags: grep

Hi I have a file which contains lines with word 'UNGROUPED' several times. But I want to extract the first line with 'UNGROUPED' and line with the word 'UNMAPPED' (present in file only once). Can I do it with 'grep'? Here is reproducible example:

```
UNMAPPED    0.445
UNGROUPED   0.215
UNGROUPED|g__Agathobaculum.s__Agathobaculum_butyriciproducens   0.001
UNGROUPED|g__Akkermansia.s__Akkermansia_muciniphila 0
UNGROUPED|g__Alistipes.s__Alistipes_finegoldii  0
UNGROUPED|g__Alistipes.s__Alistipes_putredinis  0.001
```

Also, it would be great if the numeric value at the end of the lines can be added and the result is printed.

Thanks

Comment: so, you have a file with UNMAPPED many times and UNGROUPED many times, yes?  And you just want to iterate line by line and get a total sum of the numerical values for each group and output it?  You might need something more complex than `grep` to do this...

Comment: @steeldriver i think you misread where the quotation marks are.

Comment: I have edited the question little bit. Sorry, I think I am unable to make the query clear to you. Actually I want to print the lines with UNMAPPED and the first line with UNGROUPED so as to see the numerical value at the end of the line. In addition, I asked if it is easily possible to add those values and print the result. Thanks for your time,

Comment: I think if you provide sample output of what you're looking for it'll be easier to help get an idea of what your 'end goal' is - using this example you've provided, you should be able to manually give us an idea of what your end-goal is here.

Comment: Thanks sir Thomas Ward. I want to just add 0.445 from UNMAPPED and 0.215 from UNGROUPED. Thus it will just print `My_file_name.txt : 0.660`.     Here, (0.445+0.215 = 0.660)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="UNGROUPED" || $1=="UNMAPPED" {res+=$2} END {print FILENAME, res}' My_file_name.txt
```

- If first field is `UNGROUPED` or `UNMAPPED`, add the second field to a variable `res`.
- At the end of the file, print that variable together with the filename.
- The other lines are not matched, because the delimiter defaults to a blank in `awk`.

Output:

```
My_file_name.txt 0.66
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pLumo. It works

Comment: @DEEPCHANDA please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: How to do that? I don't know @steeldriver

Comment: @DEEPCHANDA please see [How do I “accept” an answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) and also [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)